# Capture word starting and ending with colon

Tags: javascript, regex

My requirement is to capture the words starting and ending with colon `(:)` character. Can you help me making refer for that.

I tried `\b\:.*\:\b` but it didn't work

Comment: `but it didn't work` - Please be specific.

Comment: Do words contain non-alpha characters?

Comment: The problem with \b is that it only works when the contained words contain word characters. ":" is not a word character.

Comment: What is the expected output if string is like `hello :world: this:is:test`

Comment: @NathanCooper, `\:\b.*\b\:`

Comment: @Basilevs Yeah, that looks like it would work. I was just saying that \b doesn't do what the OP thinks it does.

Comment: It doesn't do what many people think it does, either, until we get Unicode regexes in JavaScript. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with this one ? -

```
/\:\w+\:/g
```

Tried in firebug console -

```
var re = /\:\w+\:/g
console.log(":tetest: xdsds :sdsd:".match(re))
```

an output is - `[":tetest:", ":sdsd:"]`

Comment: `:ہندوستانی:` does not match, neither `:кириллица:`

Comment: also fails on ":entrée:" and any other word with diacritics borrowed by English, no need to go as far as completely non-ascii scripts. Also fails on hyphens, which may or may not be what you want: ":regex-o-tron:"

Comment: Solution: use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) with the following pattern: `:\p{L}+:`.

Comment: :aaa::aa It is matching this word too which doesn't ends with colon

Answer (score 1):

`\b` counts both ":" and any non-ascii character (letters like "é") as a non-word character. So you can't really use it.

`\w` only matches ascii letters, so, same problem.

A possible solution that doesn't fail miserably with Unicode is:

```
/:\S+?:/g
```

Comment: :aaa::aa It is matching this word too which doesn't ends with colon

Comment: Well, it's matching the :aaa: part. You still haven't really explained the precise behavior you want, particularly nu11p01n73R's question. Do you consider that a "word" is something delimited by whitespace? anything else than whitespace (punctuation…)?